# Chceck if row meet the requirements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bounds

I have such a features in a row

```
...
|  2  |  2.3  |  14  |  1050  |  6  |  500  |  300  |  1500  |
...
```

I have upper and lower bounds. How do I check if my row meets those bounds?

Comment: Do you want just to check the min and max values of the row? Did I get it right? And is this a matrix row? Is it in a .txt file? be more precise.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντίνοςΑτζαράκης This is a matrix row 1x8 of matrix 50x8. Bounds are also 1x8. I need to check if every number(i,j) meets the upper or lower bound(j). I am sure that there are some which should pass the test. I tried for but it didn't look good... Then I tried     numbers(i, 1:8) >= lb & numbers(i, 1:8) <= ub which failed.

Comment: so for every cell are there 2 bounds? Did I get it right?

Comment: For every cell there are 2 bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that?

```
upper_bounds = rand(1, 10) %random upper bound
lower_bounds = upper_bounds/5 %random lower bound    
row = rand(1, 10) %random row
% answer
satisfied = (row < upper_bounds & row > lower_bounds)
```

Output:

```
upper_bounds =

    0.1067    0.9619    0.0046    0.7749    0.8173    0.8687    0.0844    0.3998    0.2599    0.8001


lower_bounds =

    0.0213    0.1924    0.0009    0.1550    0.1635    0.1737    0.0169    0.0800    0.0520    0.1600


row =

    0.4314    0.9106    0.1818    0.2638    0.1455    0.1361    0.8693    0.5797    0.5499    0.1450


satisfied =

     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your upper and lower bounds are respectively stored in upper_bound and lower_bound:

```
satisfies_upper_bound = (max(features) < upper_bound);
satisfies_lower_bound = (min(features) > lower_bound);
is_acceptable = (satisfies_upper_bound & satisfies_lower_bound);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. I have checked what is happening when I do

```
A <= lb & A >= ub
```

I got 8x8 matrix which is not what I needed. I transposed the lb and ub so in the end I have got 1x8 (0|1) matrix which was solving my problem.

Thank you all for contribution!